# How to transpose row to column based on Id column

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to convert rows into columns based on column A. Can someone help me with either a formula or any setup?

[image]

Comment: I guess I am a little confused with what you are trying to do. What rows do you want to transpose, and based on what criteria?

Comment: Based on Column A. We have 3 unique values in Column A (1,2,3).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible to create something like that with excel formula.I try to create a code which may help using VBA.

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LR As Long, LC As Long, i As Long, No As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        .Cells(LR + 3, 1).Value = "Event_Id"
        .Cells(LR + 4, 1).Value = "1"
        .Cells(LR + 5, 1).Value = "2"
        .Cells(LR + 6, 1).Value = "3"

        For i = 2 To LR
            No = .Cells(i, 1).Value

            If No = "1" Then

                LC = .Cells(LR + 4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

                If .Cells(LR + 3, LC + 1).Value = "" Then
                    .Cells(LR + 3, LC + 1).Value = "Unit_Id"
                End If
                    .Cells(LR + 4, LC + 1).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value

                If .Cells(LR + 3, LC + 2).Value = "" Then
                    .Cells(LR + 3, LC + 2).Value = "Qty"
                End If
                    .Cells(LR + 4, LC + 2).Value = .Cells(i, 3).Value

            ElseIf No = "2" Then
                LC = .Cells(LR + 5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

                If .Cells(LR + 3, LC + 1).Value = "" Then
                    .Cells(LR + 3, LC + 1).Value = "Unit_Id"
                End If
                    .Cells(LR + 5, LC + 1).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value

                If .Cells(LR + 3, LC + 2).Value = "" Then
                    .Cells(LR + 3, LC + 2).Value = "Qty"
                End If
                    .Cells(LR + 5, LC + 2).Value = .Cells(i, 3).Value

            ElseIf No = "3" Then
                LC = .Cells(LR + 6, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

                If .Cells(LR + 3, LC + 1).Value = "" Then
                    .Cells(LR + 3, LC + 1).Value = "Unit_Id"
                End If
                    .Cells(LR + 6, LC + 1).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value

                If .Cells(LR + 3, LC + 2).Value = "" Then
                    .Cells(LR + 3, LC + 2).Value = "Qty"
                End If
                    .Cells(LR + 6, LC + 2).Value = .Cells(i, 3).Value

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```